# Insert into postgres database using PDO

Tags: php, postgresql, php-pgsql

I am trying to insert some data into postgres database using pdo connection in php. Connection is successful, but insert query is giving error in syntax, i cant figure it out what is the fault in my syntax.

```
$dbcon->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$id = "12345";
$name = "Sueaj Roy";
$fname = "Biplab Roy";
$aadhaar = "5678973";
$dob = "22/12/90";
$statement = $dbcon->prepare("INSERT INTO user (full_name, father_name, dob, aadhaar_no, id) VALUES (:A,:B,:C,:D,:E)");
$statement->bindValue(':A', $name);
$statement->bindParam(':B', $fname);
$statement->bindParam(':C', $dob);
$statement->bindParam(':D', $aadhaar);
$statement->bindParam(':E', $id);
$statement->execute();
```

[image]

**my table**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user` is a reserved word in Postgres. If you name any object `user` you have to enclose the name in double quotes to address it.

```
INSERT INTO "user"
            ...
```